# Opening a Python file in desktop folder

Tags: python-3.x

Working on a Mac I have individual `.py` files on my desktop that open and run fine when typing the following in the terminal:

```
cd desktop
python3 filename.py
```

Now, I created a folder named Python on the Desktop to better store these files but I can't seem to access it, no matter what I try.   I have tried the following

```
cd desktop/Python  (file or directory doesn't exist)
cd desktop/Python python3 filename.py (file or directory doesn't exist)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run `ls -d ~/desktop/*/` and see if your python directory is there.

Comment: It is there, I think, that returns:  /Users/me/desktop/Python/      I should add that I replaced * with Python in your above code.  * returned 'No Such File or Directory'

Comment: Why are you trying to `cd` to `filename.py`?

Comment: I am not sure?  I thought that was how to get to the correct path?  cd desktop got me to my desktop, which I was able to run the files from originally (see original post).  Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: That is very odd,  Can you show the exact result for `ls -ld ~/desktop/Python/`?

Comment: Hi John, that returns the following....... ls: illegal option -- ~
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]      EDIT: Actually I missed a space after the ld.   Second run returns this:   drwxr-xr-x  2 me  staff  68 Sep 27 17:40 /Users/me/desktop/Python

Comment: You mentioned that `cd desktop/Python` fails.  Try `cd ~/desktop/Python`

Comment: Ahh, that did it!  Thanks much John!

Answer (score 0):

```
cd desktop/Python # (file or directory doesn't exist)
```

There are two kinds of path specifications: paths can be *absolute* or *relative*.  An absolute path begins with `/`.  A path that does not begin with `/` is interpreted relative to the current directory.  `desktop/Python` is a relative path.  The directory that it indicates varies depending on what the current directory is.

`~/desktop/Python` is, by contrast, an absolute path.  It points the same place regardless of what the current directory is.  If one wants a `cd` command to work without knowing where one currently is in the directory structure, an absolute path should be used:

```
cd ~/desktop/Python
```

Or:

```
cd "$HOME/desktop/Python"
```

#### The shell and tilde expansion

The shell interprets `~/` to mean the home directory, `$HOME`.  Note, though, that this is only done if `~/` is outside of quotes.  If it is in quotes, either single or double quotes, it is a relative path referring  to a direct literally named `~`.